# Is there a serial voting epidemic happening lately?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I have noticed (just recently) maybe on 2 or 3 separate days (in the last 2 weeks) getting 4 or 5 serial votes, it looks like someone just goes through the last batch of answers and upvotes them randomly.

Has anyone noticed this more of-late, because i personally have never experienced it before these instances.

Is it a happy-troll, a bot, or is it that i am just awesome lately.

Comment: FWIW looking at your rep history it really makes no difference.

Comment: Hah and some clever clogs just went and voted down 5 questions, that was kind of cheeky, though it was funny

Comment: Wrote any answers lately where someone responded as if you absolutely rocked their world?

Comment: @Gimby im not sure, however every now and again, i feel like this http://i.imgur.com/dy0Jp.gif